# How do I preview a string containing unsupported Unicode characters

Tags: windows, unicode

I have a string. It contains a lot of unicode characters (mostly the flags). These are not supported on Windows. Is it possible to preview them anywhere using some online service?

Ideally, I want to enter the full string and preview it instead of searching for equivalent image for each character?

Comment: Define "preview"? Can you see these? ️ If so, there's your preview.

Comment: Preview = Convert the string to an image so I can see the characters regardless of support by my device.

Comment: You 'convert the 'string' to an image by having the fonts/glyphs for those characters.

Comment: @Tetsujin Nope. I think you also need OS support for it. Windows doesn't have it.

Comment: I hadn't realised Windows was so backward as to not support emoji - but I just confirmed it. Maybe eventually they'll catch up to the 21st century. I've no idea how you see glyphs you can't see, in that case. Windows version of my comment above vs the view I get normally  - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgj9w.png

Comment: @Tetsujin I see the first version. Windows do support emoji and unicode but they seem to have exclude some of them like flags for some political reason. Pretty annoying

Comment: Um. @Tetsujin's actually correct. System reads only character codes. To display a code it needs to be mapped to a visual character. What character is mapped depends on which font is used - compare WinDings and Arial. So font provides the OS support for any glyphs. Try [https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Flags.html](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Flags.html)

Comment: @Peregrino69 If it's true, why his comment shows flag on android but characters on PC? Superuser.com is using the same font on both PC and android?

Comment: It doesn't matter what SU uses - your system doesn't see characters, it sees only codes.  Whatever you see on your screen is rendered by the device according to the codes it receives from SU. Android has been using for a goodly time now font sets that contain emoticons and other similar including flags, Windows not, so Android and iOS devices can display things Windows cannot. A website is designed to use certain font and can suggest it to the client, but the user who runs the client has complete control over it :-)

Comment: [Here](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/iso3166)'s an incomplete list of unicode sequences that are supposed to translate to flags. "Supposed to", as I'm pretty sure there isn't an official standard yet like there is for ASCII or ANSI codes. As long as there isn't, it's up to the font creator to decide how to use the extended character sets. But I think that's sort of an industry standard by now.

Comment: Case in point... both my MacOS and Debian have fonts that contain flags at the extended part, but they use different fonts. [Compare the text and flags in this image.](https://imgur.com/a/C4eRgIy) The difference in text comes from the fact that the site sends a suggestion, and my systems use whatever they think is the closest alternative to the requested font face.

Answer (score 1):

Flags are represented in Unicode as a 2 character string; for example the flag of Andorra is represented by Unicode pair 1F1E6 1F1E9.

- [This page](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/iso3166) shows a list of flags with their corresponding Unicode pairs
- You can search for characters / emojis / flags / etc. by Unicodes and Unicode pairs in [this page](http://www.iemoji.com/)

For a system to be able to show them correctly, it needs a font that can show these extended character tables. Basically a font that can display emojis. These have been standard in Android- and iOS-devices for quite some time. They're also installed in MacOS (at least since Mojave) and some Linux distros. Windows seems to be still lacking these fonts.